# Why i cannot see my SHA-1 Key when running commands from terminal?

Tags: android, sha1, keytool

I'm trying to create a SHA 1 key and a keytool file so i can use it in my project.

I followed example provided here:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

However, when I run the command, I get no SHA-1 or keytoll file!

The command I am running is this:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

This is what I see in the terminal:

[image]

Am I missing something here? where can I find the SHA 1 key?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SHA 1 key in android studio right side gridle project option then go to inside Task then android then signingReport.you can find in android monitor if you have any query then ask me.

Comment: I'm not using android studio.

Comment: http://hackerspace.kinja.com/the-easy-way-to-find-your-md5-and-sha1-in-eclipse-for-a-1505263073

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

The reason is `"` was missing in my original code.